ArcTan action in more than two dimensional space
There is a four-dimensional vector, (w, x, y, z).
Can ArcTan, ArcTan[w, x, y, z] be applied? Or what is the alternative to it?

Makes no sense.

@ David G. Stork: This platform is about discussing "Make no sense" things and "Making them sensible". See the answer below!

ArcTan gives a vector?  That's what I mean by "makes no sense."

One possible interpretation, if you are hoping to get the (hyper)spherical coordinate angles of the point. This is a generalization of the 2D "spherical" coordinates known as "polar coordinates."
ClearAll[atan4];
atan4[x__] := With[{v = {x}},
   Rest@CoordinateTransformData[
      "Cartesian" -> {"Hyperspherical", "Euclidean", 4},
      "Mapping",
       v] /; Length[v] === 4
   ];
SeedRandom[0];
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4]
atan4 @@ v
(*
{0.304936, 0.266141, 0.365626, 0.132704}
{0.996526, 0.970733, 0.348164}
*)

Generalization to any dimension $n \ge 2$:
ClearAll[atan];
atan[n_Integer /; n >= 2][x__] := With[{v = {x}},
   Rest@CoordinateTransformData[
      "Cartesian" -> {"Hyperspherical", "Euclidean", n},
      "Mapping",
       v] /; Length[v] === n
   ];
SeedRandom[0];
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]
atan[Length@v] @@ v
(*
{ 0.304936,  0.266141, 0.365626,  0.132704, 0.870404,
  0.952376, -0.523097, 0.275125, -0.797803, 0.291049}

{ 1.3953,   1.41541,   1.35389,   1.49073,  1.01656,
  0.826786, 2.10084,   1.2575,   2.79178}
*)

Comparison with ArcTan — note the return value of atan[n] is always a vector, even in 1D:
SeedRandom[0];
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]
atan[Length@v] @@ v
ArcTan @@ v
(*
{0.304936, 0.266141}
{0.717569}
0.717569
*)


Variations with different usages: atan[x__] :=  With[{v = {x}},  Rest@CoordinateTransformData[ "Cartesian" -> {"Hyperspherical", "Euclidean", Length[v]}, "Mapping",  v]];
or
atan[v_?VectorQ] :=   Rest@CoordinateTransformData[ "Cartesian" -> {"Hyperspherical", "Euclidean", Length[v]}, "Mapping", v];
